# Geodatabase feature class not drawing in inset maps, but draws fine in main map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I am working with some census data, identifying minority populated blocks (shown in blue), in a geodatabase.  The blocks draw fine in my main map but do not draw in either inset. They can be selected (highlighted polygons in both insets) from the both inset Data frames, as shown in the screen capture below.

[image: selected polygons]

Neither inset has any scale restrictions set to the data frame.

The other weird thing about this situation is when I turn the basemap on or off in either inset (but not my main data frame, I get the following error:

[image: error]

I am sure this is related to the feature class is not rendering, but I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you export the block fc to a shapefile and add it to the inset dataframe?

Comment: @artwork21 that did the trick. If you have any insight to what was going on there, would you mind educating me? It was driving me crazy.

Comment: I think the original fc XY feature extent may of been out of wack.  What happens if you re-import the shp back to the gdb and add it back to the inset dataframe?